# During Spring unit test, data written to db but test not seeing the data

Tags: unit-testing, spring

I wrote a test case that extends `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.  The single test case I've written creates an instance of class User and attempts to write it to the database using Hibernate.  The test code then uses `SimpleJdbcTemplate` to execute a simple select count(*) from the user table to determine if the user was persisted to the database or not.  The test always fails though.  I was suspect because in the Spring controller I wrote, the ability to save an instance of User to the db is successful.

So I added the Rollback annotation to the unit test and sure enough, the data is written to the database since I can even see it in the appropriate table -- the transaction isn't rolled back when the test case is finished.

Here's my test case:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:context-daos.xml", 
    "classpath:context-dataSource.xml", 
    "classpath:context-hibernate.xml"})
public class UserDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

  @Autowired
  private UserDao userDao;

  @Test
  @Rollback(false)
  public void teseCreateUser() {
    try {
        UserModel user = randomUser();
        String username = user.getUserName();

        long id = userDao.create(user);

        String query = "select count(*) from public.usr  where usr_name = '%s'";
        long count = simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForLong(String.format(query, username));

        Assert.assertEquals("User with username should be in the db", 1, count);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.assertNull("testCreateUser: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I think I was remiss by not adding the configuration files.

**context-hibernate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd>

   <bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
  <property name="staticField">
     <value>org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE</value>
  </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy" scope="singleton">
  <property name="namingStrategy">
     <ref bean="namingStrategy"/>
  </property>

  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

  <property name="mappingResources">
     <list>
        <value>com/company/model/usr.hbm.xml</value>
     </list>
  </property>

  <property name="hibernateProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop> 
        <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">yes 'Y', no 'N'</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="false" />
   </bean>   

   <bean id="transactionInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
  <property name="transactionManager">
     <ref local="transactionManager"/>
  </property>

  <property name="transactionAttributes">
     <props>
        <prop key="create">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="delete">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="update">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
   </bean>      
 </beans>
```

**context-dataSource.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"     value="jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost:5432/company_dev" />
        <property name="user"        value="postgres" />
        <property name="password"    value="postgres" />
     </bean>   
</beans>
```

**context-daos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="extendedFinderNamingStrategy" class="com.company.dao.finder.impl.ExtendedFinderNamingStrategy"/>
   <bean id="finderIntroductionAdvisor"    class="com.company.dao.finder.impl.FinderIntroductionAdvisor"/>

   <bean id="abstractDaoTarget" class="com.company.dao.impl.GenericDaoHibernateImpl" abstract="true" depends-on="sessionFactory">
      <property name="sessionFactory">
         <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
      </property>

      <property name="namingStrategy">
         <ref bean="extendedFinderNamingStrategy"/>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="abstractDao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
      <property name="interceptorNames">
         <list>
           <value>transactionInterceptor</value>
            <value>finderIntroductionAdvisor</value>
         </list>
       </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="userDao" parent="abstractDao">
     <property name="proxyInterfaces">
       <value>com.company.dao.UserDao</value>
     </property>

  <property name="target">
     <bean parent="abstractDaoTarget">
        <constructor-arg>
           <value>com.company.model.UserModel</value>
        </constructor-arg>
     </bean>
  </property>
  </bean>


</beans>
```

Some of this I've inherited from someone else. I wouldn't have used the proxying that is going on here because I'm not sure it's needed but this is what I'm working with.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: is your select in the same transaction? Isolation level on your transactions?

Comment: It would seem to me that the select is happening outside of the transaction but How can I determine what the isolation level might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, Hibernate (and other O/R mappers) delay the database INSERT and UPDATE statements until the transaction commit. The SELECT then does not see the data, as it is not yet written. Try explicitly requesting a session flush.

See also the documentation for an explanation and example:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing

Comment: Adding the call to Session.flush() did the trick.  This worked for save, update and delete operations.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't transactionInterceptor automatically commits?

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.java.html

Line 117:

```
commitTransactionAfterReturning(txInfo);
```

By default the flush mode should be auto, so there should be an implicit flush when commit is performed.  I have the same problem and had to solve it by manually calling flush.  That is very unsatisfying because my existing code depends on auto-flush before migrating to Spring transation manager.  I wish there is a way to tell org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager to flush after commit.